# cscope for Java and Cpp and C

Tags: java, android, c++, c, cscope

I did this for cscope to add Java capability

```
  find ./ -name *.java > cscope.files
```

Yet when I do this and suppose I want to look for a symbol , I get all references to this symbol in java only. I also want it to display the references in the C code which is present in this project. no it only shows java references to symbol i look. So now I have to delete this file cscope.files so I can look c references to this symbol.
Hm , Any Help or anyone who has a idea.
Regards
Vaishali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks like you're only finding files with the .java extension for a start:

How about:

```
find . -iname '*.java' -or \\
       -iname '*.cpp' -or  \\
       -iname '*.c' -or    \\
       -iname '*.h' -or    \\
       > cscope.files
```

Comment: How about adding config files , which have no extention. Does cscope do that. I tried but this didnt work.

Comment: @VaishaliDhakate - Unless you're specifically talking about cscopes grep function, cscope isn't going to know how to parse those anyway so you're better off just using grep for those.

Comment: Oh u mean this wont help. Looks like it is giving me the searches with all inclusive results. But I feel a lil doubtful at time. Plz clarify what u say I didnt get.

Comment: @VaishaliDhakate I'm talking about your config files, cscope won't know what to do with those.

Comment: find . -iname '\*.java' -or -iname '\*.cpp' -or -iname '\*.c' -or -iname '\*.h' > cscope.files